# Regular Expression result don't match with tester

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm new with Python...

After couple days if googling I'm still don't get it to work.

My script:

```
import re
pattern = '^Hostname=([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)'
hand = open('python_test_data.conf')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(pattern, line) :
        print line
```

Test file content:

```
### Option: Hostname
#       Unique, case sensitive Proxy name. Make sure the Proxy name is known to the server!
#       Value is acquired from HostnameItem if undefined.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# Hostname=

Hostname=bbg-zbx-proxy
```

Script results:

```
ubuntu-workstation:~$ python python_test.py
Hostname=bbg-zbx-proxy
```

But when I have tested regex in tester the result is: https://regex101.com/r/wYUc4v/1

I need some advice haw cant I get only `bbg-zbx-proxy` as script output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to split on the equals sign. You know it will always contain that and you will be able to ignore the first item in the split.

```
import re

pattern = '^Hostname=([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)'
hand = open('testdata.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search(pattern, line) :
        print(line.split("=")[1])   # UPDATED HERE
```

Answer (score 4):

You have already written a regular expression capturing one part of the match, so you could as well use it then. Additionally, change your character class to include `-` and get rid of the `line.strip()` call, it's not necessary with your expression.
In total this comes down to:

```
import re
pattern = '^Hostname=([-a-zA-Z0-9.]+)'
hand = open('python_test_data.conf')
for line in hand:
    m = re.search(pattern, line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
        #       ^^^
```

Comment: Tested. Now the result is only 'bbg'

Comment: Add `-` to your character class then.